# Maths: conflicting approaches to averaging two averages?

Tags: math, average, rating

A product is rated according to two features. The ratings for each feature are averaged, and the results delivered to us in a web service. The data might look something like:

```
Product_One:{
  "Feature_A": {
    "TotalReviewCount": 14,
    "AverageOverallRating": 4.9286,
  },
  "Feature_B": {
    "TotalReviewCount": 42,
    "AverageOverallRating": 4.3571,
  },
}
```

My working for calculating (to one decimal place) the average overall rating for the Product is:

```
4.9286 + 4.3571 = 9.2857
9.2857 / 2 = 4.64285
round(4.64285) = 4.6
```

A colleague has presented a different working, resulting in a different number:

```
(14 * 4.9286) + (42 * 4.3571) = 251.9986
251.9986 / (42 + 14) = 4.499975
round(4.499975) = 4.5
```

Whose is... best? Is one wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your colleague calculated weighted average **per review**, and you calculated average **per feature** (not taking into account number of reviews).

In general weighted average is more reliable (compare with [Center of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass))

Comment: I see! Thanks very much :)